# Android - Snap layout to top after scrolling down vertically (similar to happycog.com's top menu)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scroll, android-scrollview

In Android, is it possible to snap a layout (RelativeLayout / LinearLayout / etc.) to the top after scrolling down vertically (similar to happycog.com's top menu)?

Can this be achieved in both xml and java?

Comment: Yes, this is possible and is commonly referred to by the layout being *sticky*. There are implementations available for both [`ListView`](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) and [`ScrollView`](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems), from the same author (Emil Sjölander). Both libraries come with sample code too.

Comment: @MH., Thank you for your answer! Can you please post this as an official answer.

Comment: Absolutely, there you go. Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per earlier comment:

Yes, this is possible and is commonly referred to by the layout being *sticky*. There are implementations available for both [`ListView`](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) and [`ScrollView`](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems), from the same author (Emil Sjölander). Both libraries come with sample code too.